# Linq to Entities Many to Many Query WPF DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

I have a Many to Many relationship in SQL Server 2008:

Student table (StudentID as PK, StudentName)

Course table (CourseID as PK, CourseName)

StudentCourse (Pure Junction Table) (StudentID, CourseID both in a composite PK).

In Visual Studio 2010:

Entity model is setup properly.
I have a DataGrid bound to:

`<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CourseViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance    my:Course, CreateList=True}" />"`

This allows me to set the dataGrid columnsproperty to BOTH tables: CourseName AND to Students.StudentName.

I need to show ALL Students in ALL Courses they are in, on the same dataGrid.

My query is:

```
    ` var context = new context();
      var List = from y in context.Courses
         from z in y.Students
         select y;
         dataGrid1.ItemsSource = List;`
```

This query returns the first student in table Student in all courses and it gets repeated, but I can't show the other students that are taking the same courses AND other courses.

Question:
How can I change the query using linq to entities.  I have tried many things for many days.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try Include instead, like this:

```
var List = (from y in context.Courses.Include("Students") select y).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response.Your query doesn't repeat the same Student and shows other students in other courses, but when a Student is in the same course with another Student, this query shows ONLY the first student and I need to show ALL students in ALL courses (every relationship in the junciton table).

Comment: The result should be a list with all students and each student should have a list of all courses they're in. From the student list you should be able to iterate through each student and each course for each student to get all students and all courses. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.DATA.OBJECTS.OBJECTQUERY%601.INCLUDE%22%29;k%28INCLUDE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) for more info on Include

Comment: You are right Eirik, the datagrid shows what you describe.  I'll work on the iteration from the link provided and as soon as I got it figured out I'll post the code and mark this question as answered. Thanks for the guidance.